# Loading javascript with a Promise fails on hard refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I'm scanning a page to see if we find anything with a class of "coceon" (an image comparison JS lib), if found we then load in the cocoen scripts to then run it.

The code:

```
/* cocoen image comparison */
if ($('.cocoen').length)
{
    var cocoen_js = Promise.resolve($.cachedScript("/includes/jscripts/cocoen/js/cocoen.min.js"));
    var cocoean_jquery = Promise.resolve($.cachedScript("/includes/jscripts/cocoen/js/cocoen-jquery.min.js"));

    Promise.all([cocoen_js, cocoean_jquery]).then(() => { 
        $('.cocoen').cocoen();
      });
}
```

The trouble is, sometimes it just fails with the browser console telling me this line:

```
$('.cocoen').cocoen();
```

Fails as cocoen is not a function. So sometimes it's not loaded ready when needed. Especially so when doing a hard refresh, something seems to block it? Is there a way to ensure it's actually loaded to then run?

The cache script code if you need to see it too:

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function( url, options ) 
{
    // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
    options = $.extend( options || {}, {
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true,
      url: url
    });
   
    // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
    // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
    return jQuery.ajax( options );
};
```

Comment: Why not just call the scripts in when the page loads instead of trying determine if they need to be loaded? You're already loading in jQuery so I doubt performance would be an issue.

Comment: @Andy good question, it's really to ensure we're not loading in what we don't need all the time.

Comment: That's cool, I understand that, but it sounds like you're trying to over-complicate your code when you don't need to.